# C# Entity Framework and Business Logic

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, data-access-layer, business-logic

I have a database and I'm accessing it via EF.

```
public partial class Project
{
    public int ProjectID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ProjectAssets> ProjectAssets { get; set; }
}

public partial class ProjectAssets
{
    public int MappingID { get; set; }
    public int ProjectID { get; set; }
    public int AssetID { get; set; }

    public virtual Project Project { get; set; }
    public virtual Asset Asset { get; set; }
}

public partial class Asset
{
    public int AssetID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public short Type { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ProjectAssets> ProjectAssets { get; set; }
}
```

So, my program have only 1 active `Project` in the time.
I want to be able to bind to `Project` and display as a tree or some other way all `Asset`s and I want to be able to create new `Asset` or add existing `Asset` what belongs to other project.
If I will use the generated entities I would not be able to manage that all so I need some rules. I've already found good impl. of repositories, but still don't know how to create rules.
Do I need to create something like:

```
public class WorkProject : Project
{
    public WorkProject(Project projject){...}
    WorkAsset CreateAsset(){...}
    void AddAsset(Asset asset){...}
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How to restrict access to entities?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your question, you want to control the graph of entities which are related to a project object. You can leave the repository layer intact and put another layer (business layer) on top of it to enforce the rules.